# Appending to NumPy (Python) Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For starters, I am doing a Runge-Kutta on a three-DOF NumPy array. My array looks like this:

states = [[X], [Vx], [Y], [Vy], [Z], [Vz]]

I run my Runge-Kutta, and get my four K values, which I transpose with [newaxis]. So when I try to append the new states to my states array as follows:

`states = append(states, states[:,i] + (K1.T + 2 * K2.T + 2 * K3.T + K4.T)/6, 1)`

where "i" is a counter that starts at 0 and counts up for each iteration.

However, when I run my code my resulting states array is not two columns of six elements. It appears that I am appending a row vector instead of a column vector to my states array. I ran the code with two elements (X, Vx) in the column, and everything appended just fine (or at least my result made sense).

I have tried forcing the result of my Runge-Kutta to be a column vector, but that messes up my calculation of the K-values. I have tried variations of my append code, and still have the same result.

This is a clone of a Matlab code, and I have been unable to find anything on NumPy arrays and indexing that helps me.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
`states[:,0] = [[0], [2300], [0], [0], [-1600], [500]]` - original
`states[:,1] = [[2300], [2100], [0], [0], [-2100], [450]]` - append
`states = [[0, 2300], [2300, 2100], [0, 0], [0, 0], [-1600, -2100], [500, 450]]` - final
These are column vectors.

Comment: you cannot append to numpy arrays ... you can concatenate them and make a new list but you cannot append to them ... they are preallocated chunks of memory...

Comment: @JoranBeasley - You [can't](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)?

Comment: lol well now i feel dumb ... I never realized... so stupid :P

Comment: It might be better to think of `states` as a Python list, rather than an array.  You can easily collect arrays in a list.  Creating an array by repeatedly concatenating is poor `numpy` practice.

Comment: `np.append` is just another way of using `np.concatenate`.  It is not an in-place operation like list `append`.  Beasley is basically right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stack them instead of `appending` them.

Taken from the [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) you should one of the stack methods, for example: `np.vstack`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([2, 3, 4])
c = np.vstack((a,b))
print(c)
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [2, 3, 4]])
```

or depending on your resulting data there is also `np.hstack` (stack along first axis) and `np.dstack` (stack along third axis).

Comment: I want to go from one column to 1000 columns over 1000 seconds. Stacking appears to do rows. Can I do columns?

Comment: `np.hstack` is column-wise. But it could also be `dstack`. If you show how the input and output looks like (exemplaric) it's easier to determine which one you need.

Comment: `states = array([[X], [Vx], [Y], [Vy], [Z], [Vz]])`
    states: [[X]
                [Vx]
                [Y]
                [Vy]
                [Z]
                [Vz]]

I'm getting an EOF error with both 'hstack' and 'dstack'

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Could you edit your question to provide for example the first state, the state_to_append before stacking and what you want it to look like after stacking? Or does it already work with one of these `stack`s?

Comment: @user1187621 - EOF means you haven't closed all parenthesis in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not append arrays, if you can avoid, due to efficiency issues. Appending means changing the allocated memory size, which can run into non-contiguous memory space, hence inefficient allocation or reallocation would be necessary. These can slow down your program a lot, specially for large arrays.

If you are implementing a fixed time-step Runge-Kutta you know beforehand how many points your solution is going to have at time T. It's N = (T-t0)/h+1, where T is the final time, t0 the initial time, and h the time step. You can initialize your array with zeros (using `states = np.zeros((N,3))`) and fill the values as you go, associating the index `i` to the time `t[i] = t0 +i*h`. This would be inside the loop: 
`states[:,i+1] = states[:,i] + RK4_step(states[:,i])`,
where `RK4_step(states[:,i])` is a function returning an array (column) with your variation of the state values in one step of the Runge-Kutta method.

Even if your time-step is variable you should still do that, but with nonuniform times `t[i] = t0 +i*h`.

Or, you could use `numpy.integrate.ode_int()`, which returns the solution of an ODE at the required times.